# How can I replace a word at a specific line in a file in unix

Tags: bash, unix, replace

I've researched other questions on here, but haven't really found one that works for me. I'm trying to select a specific line from a file and replace a string on that line with another string. So I have a file named my_course. I'm trying to modify a line in my_course that starts with "123". on that line I want to replace the string "0," with "1,". Help?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility would be to use **sed**:

```
sed '/^123/ s/0/1/' my_course
```

- In the first `/../` part you just have to specify the pattern you are looking for `^123` for a line starting with 123.
- In the `s/from/to/` part you have specify the substitution to be performed.

Note that by default after substitution the file will be written to stdout. You might want to:

- redirect the output using `... > my_new_course`
- perform the substitution "in place" using the `-e` switch to sed

If you are using the destructive in place variant you might want to use `-iEXTENSION` in addition to keep a copy with the given EXTENSION of the original version in case something goes wrong.

**EDIT:** 
To match the desired lined with a prefix stored in a variable you have to enclose the sed script with double quotes `"` as using single qoutes `'` will prevent variable expansion:

```
sed "/^$input/ s/0/1/" my_course
```

Comment: i cant get it to work. im using    sed  '/^$input/ s/0,/1,' my_course

Comment: $input contains the first word of the particular line

Comment: would it be because 0, is part of a string and not a string on its own

Comment: No, the problem has to do with the quoting characters you are using `'` will prevent bash from expanding $input. You have to use an additional pair of `"` surrounding your expression to have $input expanded: `"'/^$input/ s/0/1/'"`. And don't forget the closing slash `/` in the substitution pattern as in the example you have posted.

Comment: im getting an error  No such file or directory that has to do with searching for the line... its saying no line starts with $input but there is

Comment: It shouldn't say $input but show the value stored in input if everything went all right. Are you sure you used double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'`? I'll update the post with the version that should work.

Comment: this is what is says exactly "/^222/ No such file or directory"... a line in the file starts with 222

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this:
sed -e '[line]s/old_string/new_string/' my_course

PS: the [ ] shouldn't be used, is there just to make it clear that you should put the number right before the "s".

Cheers!

In fact, the -e in this case is not necessary, I can write just

```
sed '<line number>s/<old string>/<new string>/' my_course
```

Comment: thanks but in this case i cannot use line number because my program will modify the text document and the line number wont stay constant

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me on Fedora 36, GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu):

```
sed -i '1129s/additional/extra/' en-US/Design.xml
```

I know you said you couldn't use line numbers; I don't know how to address that part, but this replaced "additional" with "extra" on line 1129 of that file.